# Limit of $\frac{n! +n^n}{1+\ln(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to find the limit of:

> $$\frac{n! +n^n}{1+\ln(n)}$$

I have $n!=o(n^n); $ and hence $n! +n^n=o(n^n) $

Since $1+\ln(n) =o(n)$ then I concluded that :

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n! +n^n}{1+\ln(n)}= +\infty $$

Did I make any mistake in the above analysis.

Comment: If you are using the "small o" $n^n \neq o(n^n) $

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen OP had it correct, $f\in o(g)$ if $\frac{f}{g}\to 0$. Whether or not it is directly useful to the problem is another matter, since we want the "smallest possible" upper bound for the analysis.

Comment: $\frac{n! +n^n}{1+\ln n}\geq \frac{n! +n!}{n+n}=(n-1)! \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

The intuition isn't wrong, but it is not a rigorous proof. With that logic, we could also say that $\log n = o(n^{n^{n^n}})$ and $n!+n^n = o(n^{n^n})$ to obtain the opposite conclusion if we were not careful. Instead deal with the inequalities directly:

$$\frac{n!+n^n}{1+\log n} > \frac{2n!}{2\log n} = \frac{n}{\log n}(n-1)! > (n-1)!$$

Comment: It seems @Sil already left this proof in the comments. I'll leave the answer up for the sake of the first part only where I explain what can go wrong with the asymptotics arguments.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=o(n^{n})$ and $b_n=o(n)$ does not imply that $\frac {a_n} {b_n} \to \infty$.

Just use the fact that numerator is $>n^{2}$ and denominator is $< n$  (for $n>1$)so the ratio is $>n$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{n! +n^n}{1+\ln(n)}=\frac{n^n}{\ln n}\frac{\frac{n!}{n^n} +1}{1+\frac1{\ln(n)}}\to\infty$$

indeed

- $n^n\ge n\cdot \ln n \implies \frac{n^n}{\ln n}\ge n\to \infty$
- $n^n\ge n\cdot n! \implies \frac{n!}{n^n}\le\frac1n\to 0$